# PowerBI - Bug in function LOOKUPVALUE?

Tags: powerbi, dax

It seems we have a very strange bug with the LOOKUPVALUE-function in PowerBI.

The following Dax-column in table `target_table` is working for 99% of our cases, but there are 2 cases which do not work, even so the IDs do exist in the target field it returns us blanks, if so `source_table[Name` is not.

```
Name_User = LOOKUPVALUE(  source_table[Name],
                          source_table[code_user],
                          target_table[code_user])
```

The id-field is just a concatenation of 2 number-fields in both tables, based on the same concatenation:

```
      code_user = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE([CompanyID],"_"),+[PersID])
```

We did check manually if there is a line in `source_table` with the `code_user`, and there is actually exactly 1 line for both cases, both having a value in the `Name` field. Unfortunately the lookupvalue-function just returns blanks for the 2 cases. To recall, every other case is working, so basically the lookup-call is tested and working.

Sometimes the following variables get underlined in the lookup-call:

`source_table[Name]`, telling us:  `"Parameter is not the correct type."`

For source_table it underlines `code_user`, telling us:  `"Cannot find name '[code_user]'"`.

Comment: Can you share some data ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi : examples for the keys (code_user): 
   7_330 
   7_2401

Comment: It stands out that the problem resolves itself after a relationship issue. But what do relationships have to do with the function LOOKUPVALUE?